# Linear regression parameters not appearning after fitting

Tags: scikit-learn

here's my code

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.3,random_state=0)

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
ml=LinearRegression()
ml.fit(x_train,y_train)
```

the output of my above code is just:

```
LinearRegression()
```

I expect the output in the LinearRegression has parameters:

```
LinearRegression(copy_X=True, fit_intercept=True, n_jobs=None, normalize=False)
```